# Problema al editar archivo .inf con Python en W10

Tags: python

estoy tratando de modificar el archivo "security-policy.inf" que contiene directivas de seguridad para Windows, estoy ocupando with open abriendo en modo lectura y después en modo escritura, ya lo hice con la librería "re" y también sin librería con bucle for, el archivo lo quise editar así con .inf y .txt, después hice copia de ambos y sobre esa quise editar y en todos los casos sigo con el mismo problema:

```
[Unicode]਍ഀ
Unicode=yes਍ഀ
[System Access]਍ഀ
MinimumPasswordAge = 0਍ഀ
MaximumPasswordAge = 45਍ഀ
MinimumPasswordLength = 8਍ഀ
PasswordComplexity = 0਍ഀ
PasswordHistorySize = 24਍ഀ
```

El archivo retorna así, pensé que el problema podría ser la lista de comprensión en mi código: r'PasswordComplexity = \d', pero lo intenté también con str y el problema sigue igual.

También ocupé el parámetro encoding de with open y 3 distintas formas, hasta le pregunté a chatGPT y tampoco se ha resuelto.

En realidad soy el único programador y estoy automatizado unos procesos de la empresa en la que trabajo y llevo días con el problema. Agradecería mucho el apoyoc:

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].La descripción de tu problema está bien, pero debieras incluir la parte relevante del código que estás utilizando en la pregunta. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil responderla. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Eso huele a problema de encoding a kilómetros... Seguramente estas leyendo el archivo con una codificación que no es la suya, modificando el final de las lineas (por ejemplo con agregar el salto de linea basta) y luego lo guardas en disco con la codificación errónea. Por ejemplo leer un archivo UTF-16 LE como UTF-8, agregar algo al final de cada linea y luego simplemente guardarlo como UTF-8 puede generar un archivo con una ristra de caracteres no renderizables al final de cada linea  como muestras...

Comment: Por cierto, es una muy mala práctica usar `open` sin especificar el encoding del archivo explícitamente, esto hace que se use un encoding dependiente de la plataforma, por ejemplo, en linux lo normal es que sea UTF-8, en Windows... con las localizaciones en español suele ser ISO 8859-1.

Comment: Agregando a lo dicho por fjsevilla, según [esta pagina](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/general-guidelines-for-inf-files#editing-inf-files-and-file-encodings), el encoding del archivo debe ser ansi o utf-16 LE. Finalmente, te recomiendo evitar para producción utilizar una regex generica para editar cualquier archivo cuya sintaxis sea compleja, como los inf. Ya que las posibilidades de que se den falsos positivos se dispara. Recomiendo en su lugar buscar un parser por internet o escribirlo por tu cuenta.

Comment: Seguí sus recomendaciones y metiendo el encoding='utf-16-le' se resolvió el problema, les agradezco mucho